# scrapy python call spider from spider

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have one spiner which scrape the page and gets all the urls.

i have another spiner which get a url and scrap on it.

i want to call the second spiner for each link i get from the first spiner.

the code for getting all links from the first spiner

```
for site in sites:
            Link = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
```

but i don't know how to call the spiner for each `Link`

help please

Answer (score 1):

I guess you better unite the two spiders and do something like:

```
def get_links(self, response):
    for site in sites:
        link = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()[0]
        yield Request(url=link, callback=self.scrape_them)

def scrape_them(self, response):
    # by now scrapy called the link and you get the response
    ...
```

Comment: This is exactly the way that i discovered to use. but i got this exception, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121941/scrapy-python-request-is-not-defined

Comment: Request is not defined, is there something i have to import please?

Comment: `from scrapy.http import Request`

Comment: +1 to you, I got this exception: ` Request url must be str or unicode, got list:` why is that please?

Comment: happy a could help :)