# scrapy python Request is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

i found an answer here:

#### code

```
for site in sites:
            Link = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            CompleteLink = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, Link)
            yield Request(Link, callback = self.parseOneCar)
```

I got this exception

```
exceptions.NameError: global name 'Request' is not defined
```

what should I import please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: `from scrapy.http.request import Request`

Extended answer: read  [the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/index.html).